# Decode packet fields using dpkt package in python

Tags: python, decode, ntp, dpkt

I am trying to print the NTP fields using dpkt. It works well except that I couldn't get the output like the one I get from tcpdump. For instance, in the attached code, I couldn't print originate_time in human readable format. I tried functions in binascii but couldn't get it right.

I am a newbie to dpkt and any pointers would be great.

```
import dpkt
import socket

def processPcap(iFile):
    f = open(iFile)
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

    for ts, buf in pcap:
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        ip = eth.data
        source = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
        destination = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
        udp = ip.data
        if ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
            if udp.dport == 123:
                ntp = dpkt.ntp.NTP(udp.data)
                print (("Timestamp:%s, Source:%s, Destination:%s, SPort:%s, DPort:%s") % (ts, source, destination, udp.sport, udp.dport))
                print ntp.flags
                print ntp.delay
                print ntp.id
                print ntp.dispersion
                print ntp.update_time
                print ntp.originate_time

    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    INPUT = "<inputFile>"
    processPcap(INPUT)
```